# can't determine definition of operator ""-""?

Tags: arrays, vhdl

i've got the error: can't determine definition of operator ""-""  for the following code. I'm not sure about accessing the indivdual bits of each unsigned in the array. What is wrong?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use Ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.genetica_type.all;

entity binario_fitness is
Port ( 
 clk : in std_logic;
 individuos: in genetica;
 adaptacao: out fitness;
 somafitness: out unsigned (7 downto 0)
 );
 end binario_fitness;


 architecture Behavioral of binario_fitness is
 begin



 process (clk)
 begin
 If (clk 'event and clk = '1') then

 for x in 0 to 49 loop

 adaptacao(x) <= individuos(x)(0)-individuos(x)(1) +individuos(x)(2)-       individuos(x)(3)+individuos(x)(4)- individuos(x)(5)+individuos(x)(6)-individuos(x)(7);
somafitness<=(others=>'0'); 
end loop;

end if  ;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

which includes the genetica_type in another file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package genetica_type is
type genetica is array(0 to 49) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
type fitness is array(0 to 49) of unsigned (2 downto 0);
end package genetica_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to perform an arithmetic operation on type `std_logic`.

```
type genetica is array(0 to 49) of unsigned(7 downto 0)
...
individuos: in genetica;
...
adaptacao(x) <= individuos(x)(0)-individuos(x)(1)...
```

The sliced signals `individuos(X)(Y)` are actually of type `std_logic`.
The subtraction operator "-" is not defined for type std_logic, thus there is an error.
Depending on what you are actually trying to do the solution to your problem may vary.
One possiblity is:

```
adaptacao(x) <= "00"&individuos(x)(0 downto 0) - "00"&individuos(x)(1 downto 1) + "00"&individuos(x)(2 downto 2) - etc.
```

This will work because the one bit slices `individuos(x)(y downto y)` will retain the type of the sliced vector, i.e. `unsigned` in this case.

From the definition of numeric_std.vhd:

```
type UNSIGNED is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
```

Comment: The length must also be handled, since result in `adaptacao(x)` is type `unsigned (2 downto 0)`, thus with length 3, but `individuos(x)(0 downto 0)` has length of only 1, which will also be the result after the `-` and `+` operators.  Thus prepend `("00" & ...` in start of calculation to operate on 3 bit `unsigned` throughout the operations, like `("00" & individuos(x)(0 downto 0)) - ...`, whereby the final length will match that of `adaptacao(x)`, and accumulation is handled.

Comment: @Morten: I fixed the aflicted lines with your corrections. Alternative to prepending "00" the resize() function could be used, which is also part of the numeric_std package. `"00"&individuos(x)(0 downto 0)` would then become `resize(individuos(x)(0 downto 0), 3)`.

Comment: Use of `resize` is a good idea, also since it requires explicit parenthesis, thus says that `individuos(x)(0 downto 0)` is resized, which is not the case if `"00" & ...` is prepended without paranthesis, since `-` is more binding (higher precedence) than `&`, so just prepending `"00" &` will apply to the entire result, and not the `individuos(x)(0 downto 0)` argument, whereby accumulation will not occur in the additional bits, which is probably the intention.  Finally, using the `length` attribute will be nice, like `resize(individuos(x)(0 downto 0), adaptacao(x)'length)`.

Comment: It isn't particularly clear what the result of bit wise subtraction should be either, that sounds like NAND.